# For loop for rendering OpenGL VBO

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine, vbo

I have managed to get a cube rendered in OpenGL using a VBO. My next goal is actually creating a for loop to create multiple cubes. I'm stuck on this part though, do I put this code:

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vertexBufferID);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Into a for loop? Wouldn't I have to use some sort of glPopMatrix command along with a translate function? I barely understand how to create one cube in a VBO, so sorry if its obvious whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following way:

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vertexBufferID);
GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < cubeCount; i++) {
  GL11.glPushMatrix();
  // do translation/rotation for cube no i
  GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
  GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Please note that the `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` way is deprecated in newer openGl versions. For you it should work because you are using `GL11`.

Comment: Thanks! How would I get the same result in newer opengl?

Comment: You wouldn't using `glPush/PopMatrix`. Instead you would create your your own shaders and pass the matrices manually to the shader. But this topic is way to broad for a comment.

Comment: Ah I see. One other problem I've come across is actually my cubes are rendered very strangely. When I put the glDrawArrays function in a for loop in the y direction, the cubes actually render farther and farther apart as the y value is increased. Why would that happen?

Comment: I figured it out, I accidentally put glTranslatef outside of the glPushMatrix function!